# Ansible: expect -> invalid command name

Tags: ansible, expect

I want to use the expect function with ansible to install a .bin file with preanswers. But i get this error.

```
"stderr": "invalid command name \"/opt/atlassian-jira-software-7.8.1-x64.bin\"\n    while executing\n\"/opt/atlassian-jira-software-7.8.1-x64.bin\"",
```

However also i cant execute other unix simple commands...

My code:

```
- name: Upgrade Jira
   shell: |
     /opt/{{ jiraExec }}

     expect "OK [o, Enter], Cancel [c]"
     send "o\n"

     expect "Express Install (use default settings) [1], Custom Install (recommended for advanced users) [2], Upgrade an existing JIRA installation [3, Enter]"
     send "3\n"

     expect "[/opt/atlassian/jira]"
     send "\n"

     expect "Yes [y, Enter], No [n]"
     send "y\n"

     expect "Upgrade [u, Enter], Exit [e]"
     send "u\n"

     expect "Yes [y, Enter], No [n]"
     send "n\n"
  args:
     executable: /usr/bin/expect
```

And i have no possibility to use the pexpect module.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the spawn command:

```
spawn /opt/{{ jiraExec }}
```

Also, for any string containing `[...]` use Tcl's single quoting mechanism: the square brackets are Tcl's command substitution syntax (think backticks in sh):

```
expect {OK [o, Enter], Cancel [c]}
```

I found a similar example: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/shell_module.html?highlight=shell#examples

Answer (score 0):

The error didn't complain about `expect`, please check your Jira file path and you should consider using [JIRA unattended installation](https://confluence.atlassian.com/adminjiraserver071/unattended-installation-855475683.html)

```
- name: Upgrade Jira
   shell: /opt/atlassian-jira-software-X.X.X-x64.bin -q -varfile response.varfile
```

- Where jira-software.X.X.X is the JIRA version you downloaded.
- -q instructs the installer to run in unattended mode (quietly).
- -varfile specifies the location and name of the configuration file containing the options used by the installer.

Comment: my question is about to find a solution and not to find alternative ways..

Comment: as I mentioned in my answer check your path and its not alternative, its the correct way to do.

Comment: the path is correct, the error shows "invalid command name" and not like "file not found".
Also a unattended upgrade is not possible, only installation

Comment: "invalid command name ... while executing ..." is a Tcl/expect style error message, so expect is running but there are problems in the code.