# Ansible shell module variable (Tcl's quoting mechanism:)

Tags: ansible, tcl

I am trying to use ansible shell module with `send` to execute a python script.

```
- name: encrypt password
  shell: |
    spawn python3 "/usr/local/bin/encryptor.py"
    expect -re "Enter data for encryption:"
    send {"{{ secret }}"}
    send "\n"
    expect eof
  args:
    executable: /usr/bin/expect
```

The issue is that the password to encrypt has a `[` in it so, following the answer here [Ansible: expect -> invalid command name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49529954/ansible-expect-invalid-command-name), I have to wrap the secret in {} as per the code above.
However when I log what is being entered into the tool I see it is encrypting `\"password[\"` when the variable `secret` is just `password[`. Why is it adding the escaped quotes and how do I remove them so it just encrypts `passowrd[`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
- name: encrypt password
  shell: |
    spawn python3 "/usr/local/bin/encryptor.py"
    expect -re "Enter data for encryption:"
    send {{ "{" ~ secret ~ "}" }}
    send "\n"
    expect eof
  args:
    executable: /usr/bin/expect
```

Comment: What a complicated mix of quoting that is!